# Latest value in PowerBi from ASA

Tags: powerbi, azure-stream-analytics

Is it possible to show the latest value that has arrived in PowerBi from Stream Analytics?
In the card diagram type for example I imagine having a filter value for a measurementtime field selecting latest value or something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best you can do right now is use Q&A to ask a question like "show value in the last 10 seconds".  It's a valid request, could you submit an item through support.powerbi.com?

Comment: I did that Thx. Can you save such questions or results in a diagram and show it on dashboard?

Comment: Yes.  Next to the visual in the Q&A view is a 'pin' button.  When you press that it shows on the dashboard.