# Can I make a report for the last hour only

Tags: powerbi

I'm using Power BI (on the web) and I'll like to make a report showing the last hour only for a near-real time report. I can make a filter but the date/time is fixed and I want to show only the values of the last hour. Is that posible?

Comment: What is your source system? Have you scheduled an hourly refresh in Power BI or is the source a live connection to the database?

Comment: It's sourced from an event hub query. And the events arrive as they are prodiced.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a Stream Analytics query reading from Event Hubs and writing to Power BI you can use Q&A inside Power BI to filter to "in the last hour" as described here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/32227774/5070440

Then after you are happy with your Q&A tile you can pin it.

Comment: But it shows a value only and I want the graph with the values of the last hour only.

Comment: You can ask a fuller question such as "show sum of sales by date as a line chart in the last 1 hour". Or if you want to start with a Q&A question "in the last 1 hour" then click the Visualizations tab on the right and manually customize the chart to make it a line chart as you see fit.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to set up periodic refresh of your data source as GregGalloway pointed out - however likely more frequently than once an hour if you need stats from the current past hour,

Would it be an option to edit the data import query?

Would it be an option to create the report using power BI desktop, applying filter in the "edit query" view, and then publishing it?

Comment: I'll try to create the report in the Desktop version (I don't have it installed yet).

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a tile level filter on the data you want to display on PBi to select values starting a given time. However this will only work on Reports not Dashboards in PBi.

Hope this helps!